# Spark Where Field in Subquery multiple columns

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I’m trying to filter a table using a subquery in the where clause

```
Select * 
From table_a
Where
table_a.date in (select date_x, date_y from table_calendar)
```

However, the subquery produces one row and two columns spawning an error. How can this subquery filter be accomplished? Array?

Answer (score 0):

That's expected, if you have a single column on the left side of `IN` operator, you need a query that returns a single column.

You probably want:

```
Select * 
From table_a
Where
table_a.date in (select date_x from table_calendar
                 union all
                 select date_y from table_calendar)
```